# Bonjour packet trace

Tags: bonjour

Can someone please let me know if there is some blog/webpage/tutorial which clearly describes the packet traces involved in Apple Bonjour protocol? I understand how PTR, SRV and A/AAAA records play their role, but I want to actually get trace of bonjour in action, hope some of you could help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best thing would be to listen to packets (through something like Wireshark, TCPDump, e.t.c) being sent to the multicast address `224.0.0.251` on port `5353`. They're pretty much standard DNS packets, only sent over multicast.

Comment: They are, but the latest iPhone does not by default send these packets. If possible, can someone give me a simple trace for the same?

Comment: @P.Prasad, It depends what service you're trying to discover/advertise- is it something in particular? And are you specifically trying to capture data from an iPhone?